# Intellij Gradle terminal ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

In IntelliJ IDEA, using the Gradle window I am able to execute any and all Gradle tasks. However, when I try and execute the same tasks through the terminal window within the IDE, it hits me with the following error:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

This occurs when using gradle and gradlew. In IntelliJ -> File -> Project Structure -> Project then SDK is set correctly to 1.8. Any suggestions for resolving this so I can use the terminal to execute Gradle tasks would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Set the `JAVA_HOME` variable to root directory of your installation
On Linux, it will start with `/usr/lib/jvm`, try `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java`
On macOS/OS X, it will start with `/Library/Java` or `/System/Library/Java`
On Windows, it will start with `C:\Program Files\Java` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java`

Comment: Out of curiosity, any idea why executing tasks from IntelliJ's Gradle window worked when JAVA_HOME was not set?

Comment: IntelliJ could internally set this. Environment, although very difficult to change on Windows by user, can be changed in one call to `setenv` or `putenv`. My IDE I wrote once for fun (don't ask for it, it was very ugly) set such variables for gradle

Comment: If you did everything correctly and it still doesn't work, try **restarting** your machine

Comment: The error goes away and `gradlew` works when I set the `JAVA_HOME` path to `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/<your-jdk-version`, for me it was specifically `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.1/` following @TopSekret  comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an environment variable set for this to work.  You can simply type in the command line:

```
export JAVA_HOME=<PATH to your Java Home>
```

Or you can put that line in your .rc file.  On a mac you can do this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
```

More information can be found here:
http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-set-javahome-environment-in.html

Comment: Thanks. Working on windows system so changed 'export' to 'set' and all was well.

Answer (score 14):

go to Java installation (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk ********) and copy the address file. Right click the "my **computer**" select "**Properties**" or go to "**Control Panel > System and Security > System**". Select "**Advanced system settings**" then click the "**Environment Variables**" button. Click **System Variables, New**  write Variable Name to "**JAVA_HOME**" and write Variable Value to **Java installation folder address** then click OK finish it.

[image]

Comment: This answer is platform specific to Windows and I don't see original question mentioning OS.

Comment: So what? It helped many people better than accepted one.

Comment: Don't forget to restart your Idea/Android Studio after this.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is for the case when [Ubuntu app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6#activetab=pivot:overviewtab) is installed over Windows. So in Windows, I can run Ubuntu terminal. My Android Studio is installed on Windows. And I try to run gradle from the Ubuntu terminal. I tried to set up JAVA_HOME to multiple addresses via Ubuntu terminal:
export JAVA_HOME=/mnt/c/...
But nothing helped, including java address provided by Ubuntu ("whereis java" command):
/usr/share/java

Then I merely did the same using Windows terminal (Command Prompt). And gradle worked.