# JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH. bitbucket pipeline

Tags: java, bitbucket

Hi i tried to execute a gradle command in bitbucket pipeline

```
definitions:
  services:
    java:
      image: openjdk:8
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build And Test
        services:
          - java
        script:
          - bash ./gradlew clean build
          - bash ./gradlew test
    - step:
        name: configure gcloud
        deployment: test
        image: google/cloud-sdk:214.0.0-alpine
        services:
          - java
          - docker
        caches:
          - gradle
        script:
          - gcloud auth configure-docker --quiet
          - docker login -u _json_key -p "$GCR_JSON_KEY" https://gcr.io
          - bash ./gradlew bake -Penv=test -PisRelease=false --info --stacktrace
```

when it tried to execute the latest task

it give the error 
JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

AS you see there's a java image and it works in the first step
but in the second step if failed and this is the issue.

Comment: see this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449882/intellij-gradle-terminal-error-java-home-is-not-set][1]

Comment: In the first step it works well, but in the second step it's not, but it should be!

Answer (score 1):

You had set JAVA_HOME? If not, read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/821-0917/inst_jdk_javahome_t/index.html)

> To set JAVA_HOME, do the following:
>
> a. Right click My Computer and select Properties.
>
> b. On the Advanced tab, select Environment Variables, and then edit
>   JAVA_HOME to point to where the JDK software is located, for example,
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_02.

Comment: In the first step it works well, but in the second step it's not, but it should be!