# How to publish a library to your android studio project?

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I have a library and I want to use it in my astudio project. I tried running the command "gradlew publishToMavenLocal" and received the following error-JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Comment: have you tried to search for solutions regarding your error ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intellij Gradle terminal ERROR: JAVA\_HOME is not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449882/intellij-gradle-terminal-error-java-home-is-not-set)

Answer (score 0):

You can choose which JDK use in File->Project Structure->SDK Location

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzIsg.png)

Or add Variable like in this manual for Windows
https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-on-windows-10/

or for Linux in this answer
[How to set JAVA_HOME in Linux for all users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users)

If JAVA_HOME is the main problem for publishing you'l see your library at .m2 folder in your local gradle repositories

Don't forget add mavenLocal() in your build.gradle repositories