# JDK, SDK, and Gradle errors trying to build a Unity game for Android

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-gradle-plugin, java-home, android-sdk-2.1

The question:
My environmental variable JAVA_HOME is set to the location of my manual installation of Java, so why is Unity claiming it is an invalid directory?

Supporting information:

I'm using Unity to build a game for Android phones with the intent on putting it on the Google Play Store for a client. We need to use a Google Ad plugin for managing ads in the game. However, when I put the plugin into the project I can no longer build the game.

When going to `Assets > External Dependency Manager > Android Resolver > Resolve`, it claims it succeeds.

But when I try `Assets > External Dependency Manager > Android Resolver > Force Resolve` or even building the project I get a failure and a perplexing error.

Originally I had the same problem as: [Intellij Gradle terminal ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449882/intellij-gradle-terminal-error-java-home-is-not-set)

When I tried the solutions there as well as following the steps at: https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10

I've tried setting the environment variable both to the independent java installation as well as the location of Unity's JDK module and got an error that they were both invalid directories:

[image: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory 01]

[image: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory 02]

When I try to build I get the same error plus some additional errors:

[image: Console error printouts]

[image: Failed to update Android SDK]

I am unsure if the SDK error is related or not.

I already tried toggling these off and on, and even changing the installation targets to manual installations:

[image: External SDK Tools settings]

Possibly relevant information:

- Using Unity 2019.3.0f6
- InMobi Google Ads Unity Mediation Plugin Version 3.0.0
- Windows 10 Pro

Java JDK 14.0.1

Comment: Maybe make the question a bit more clear? Good post but with all the info, I get a little lost on what the overall question is.

Comment: Sorry, too much detail and losing the point is a bad habit I'm working on breaking.

My problem is that I don't know what is causing the problem. For now I'm asking why / how to debug why Unity can't find my Java installation. It keeps saying that my JAVA_HOME directory is an invalid directory, despite being the location of my Java installation. I set the Environment variable following the steps in my second link: https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10

Answer (score 1):

If Unity can't find `JAVA_HOME` it won't do anything, have you tried checking if you have that `Environment Variable` set correctly?

Check this [thing](https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=389:configurar-java-en-windows-variables-de-entorno-javahome-y-path-cu00610b&catid=68&Itemid=188).

Maybe you will need a `Restart` on you computer to see the changes.

Comment: I tried that and already followed the steps [link]( https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10)here, which essentially are the same steps.

In a fresh project Unity has no problem, but once I add in the Google Ads plugin Unity suddenly can't recognize the Java installation.

Comment: Same problem as OP!